# The number of solutions of a binary integer programming problem

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

A 0-1 linear programming problem with three variables can have at most $3! = 6$ acceptable solutions? Is this right or wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At most 8 solutions. Two values per variable. By rule of independence, we multiply $2^{3} = 8$.

Comment: Thanks didn't find that in my notes.

Comment: Don't rely on notes. Rely on basic principles. How did you come up with $3!$ to begin with?